# id looping with where condition in Laravel 9

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, web-applications

[image]
I send an array with ajax included category_id as shown in image. And catch these categories in controller to execute product row equal with category_id field in products table. In this case, i cannot loop the array as category_id sending from ajax for where condition  in controller. Pls guide me.......

```
public function productCategoryList(Request $request)
{
    logger($request->status);
    $data = Products::where('category_id', $request->status)->get();
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `whereIn()` on your query builder:

```php
public function productCategoryList(Request $request)
{
    logger($request->status);
    $data = Products::whereIn('category_id', $request->status)->get();
    return $data;
}
```

That would allow you to query a list of elements, instead of a single element.

The documentation for how to use `whereIn()` can be found at https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#additional-where-clauses

Comment: thank you Repox .. it's working fine as expected for me.

Comment: @YeKyaw if my answer helped you resolve your issue, please consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `whereIn()` that allows you to filter query results based on a given array of values.

```
$data = Products::whereIn('category_id', $request->status)->get();
```

Comment: really helpful tip thank you so much ..